# R package parallel stopCluster method seems to hang

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am currently working on a project for my company where I am trying to forecast demand for certain flows in parallel. For that, I'm using the following statements from the R parallel package:

```
cl = makeCluster(number_of_sessions)
parRapply(cl, range_list_small, context = context, fun = forecastDemand)
stopCluster(cl)
```

The context object in this case, is an environment which contains certain objects.
The problem is the following, I tried the script for a small sample of flows and it works perfectly. However when I runned the script for a big number of flows, it hangs for a long time (sometimes a few hours) on the stopCluster(cl) statement. I googled around, but it seems that nobody ever had the same problem before. Does somebody recognizes the problem? Or is there another way to close the cluster object. Because after this first parallel session my script has to do another parallel session for other calculations and this parallel session does not start until the stopCluster method has finished.

Comment: What is the class of the cluster object (I'm guesing it's a SOCKcluster)? What OS are you using? Finally, why can't you use the same cluster object for both parallel sessions?

Comment: Is it possible that your machine is running low on memory?